# Create an expiration date with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I need to create an expiration date using Coldfusion for a registration form.
My back end is Access but it can be MsSQL.
User fill in a registration form and the date using: `#DateFormat(Now(), "mm,dd,yyyy")#` is inserted into DB as RegistrationAccepted.
At the same time I need to insert a date that is 7 days later to ExpirationDate. This is a date where registration is expired after 7 days if user doesn't submit payment.

Is there any codes example for this? thank you

Comment: Did you make any attempt at all to look at/search through the documentation? Seems like you came right to StackOverflow without putting in even a modicum of effort on your part.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `dateFormat()` on a date going into the DB. You should be passing a date object.

Comment: Depends on the database (or maybe the JDBC drivers). Have needed to explicitly use DateFormat to get dates correctly stored before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dateAdd` and the same `dateFormat` you're already using

```
<cfset expiration_date = dateFormat(DateAdd("d",7,Now()),"mm,dd,yyyy")>
```

Comment: But do not use `dateFormat` to truncate the time in a query parameter, because it returns a string, not a date object.  Just use cfqueryparam.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateAdd](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_25.html)

```
    <cfset expiration_date = DateAdd("d",7,Now()) >
```

Comment: This will give an expiration date and time which might be too precise for the problem at hand.

Comment: So they can read the docs a bit and finetune their particular solution.